# How to test functions or the code inside $(document).ready() using Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, html, jasmine

I have multiple funcntions and a lot of code inside $(document).ready(function()). I am using jasmine to test the functions inside the ready function as well as the code inside ready() but when the test cases inside describe are executed it is not able to access the code inside the ready function().

I have multiple functions and a lot of code inside $(document).ready(function()). I am using jasmine to test the functions inside the ready function as well as the code inside ready() but when the test cases inside describe are executed it is not able to access the code inside the ready function().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function testMe(){
        testVar = true;
    }
});
```

Jasmine test suite

```
describe("test suite", function(){
    beforeEach(function () {
        testme = false
    });
    it("Test Alert Box Message For Change Modal", function() {
        expect(testme).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Kindly suggest what approach needs to be taken for the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't testing that code has been run.  Or even what the code looks like.  You are testing what the code does.

In your example test you have two problems.

1. Your `expect()` is checking the value of `testme` rather than your variable `testVar` so that will always fail because `testme` will be undefined
2. You define the function in your `$(document).ready()` but never actually execute it.  So even if you were checking the correct variable, the value won't be changed as you didn't call it.

Jasmine will have the document ready before the tests are executed, so there isn't a problem with code wrapped in this function.  So your test for a `$(document).ready()` function should make sure that data is set properly, event handlers are registered and so on.

You could spy on the jQuery `on()` function and make sure that it gets passed the correct callback. The spy's calls array gets a copy of the calling object and you would be able to inspect that to make sure that the proper selectors are used.  The callbacks themselves would be tested in a seperate test case.  Or you can setup a html fixture on the test page and then call the events yourself in later test cases.

The existence of internal functions to the `ready()` function is outside the scope of your test.  You want to have the ability to change/remove these internal functions and re-run the test to make sure that you haven't affected any functionality.  If the function can't be executed outside of the `ready()` function, it is an implementation detail and you don't need to worry about it.